# SQL XML Column displaying squares as nodes

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

for some reason, my xml column in the SQL database is showing squares as the nodes. I'm not sure where this is.

the XML is well formed. It is an object serialized from .NET.

any help would be great.

Sample from the Column:

[image]

The XML that is saved looks like this:

```
<Details>
    <Attribute Type="o">1000</Attribute>
    <Attribute Type="f">1000</Attribute>
    <Attribute Type="f">2000</Attribute>
  </Details>
```

The .NET code that serializes the object is:

```
this.Serialize(typeof(Details))
```

I am removing the following line from the XML string:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
```

Comment: What do you mean squares? Like squares characters? If this is what you meant, try to convert the node to nvarchar instead of varchar.

Comment: Can you show us a screen shot to illustrate??

Comment: Almost seems like two characters each time - maybe a CR/LF (line end, carriage return) or something like that?? This is weird.... never seen anything like that, really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the **exact** table definition? And also the 
**exact** code you use in .Net, including the serializer type and the SQL parameters types used. Is the `Detail_XML_Package` column of type `XML`, or is it some `VARCHAR` column?

That data looks like a bad encoding, like if the XML serializer is saving an Unicode stream and the column is ASCII.

Comment: It had to do with the encoding of the XML. SQL server didn't know how to read it.